# iOS Social Networking Application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am decent with objective c, and my friends and I want to start developing a social networking application, and we have plans for it and everything almost ready, but the problem is I don't know where to start. I don't know if I should code the structure of the app then write the backend code. I don't really know networking too well, and I'm not sure if I should be using parse or another cite. Basically I wanted to know if anyone had some tips on where to start, or has any guides on social networking app development that would be fantastic. Just so you guys have an idea of what I am trying to do it is kind of like snapchat, but also completely different, but the same type of style and format is what i picture.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid that this site is not intended for questions that are overly broad / open ended, and pretty much any "where to I get started" type question is going to be broad and open ended. Once you have specific questions about well defined problems you're facing this site will probably be more useful for you.

Comment: The question you asked is very vague and you wont get any answers here, your best bet would be to start by developing both client and server then any specific questions/problems you come across you can ask here.

If you don't know where to start it usually means you haven't done enough research yet! good luck on your venture.

Comment: what you want exactly do in your app, and witch social  network(s) is your target? and way you need a backend(if i get your right meaning of backend) service? in this kind of apps the social network site and services are using as backend. please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only you who is developing I would do it step by step, meaning you start with a part of the iOS App and then do the required backend functionality and test it. Afterwards you move on with the next step of the iOS App and then backend again and so on. These steps could be split into the following:

- Registration
- Login
- User profile
- Edit profile
- Posting stuff
- User feed
- Adding/following other users
- ...

If you're working as a team you can split the work, someone is doing backend someone else the App. So you're basically keeping the steps above but you can work on and test them simultaneously.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for thanks!